# Make RecyclerView height dynamic by wrapping specific number of it's child(not all child)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to make Recyclerview height to wrap a specific number of it's child views. Previously I made that work by using a custom LayoutManager:

```
public class WrapToItemCountLinearLayoutManager extends android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager {

public int numberOfChild = 0;

private static boolean canMakeInsetsDirty = true;
private static Field insetsDirtyField = null;

private static final int CHILD_WIDTH = 0;
private static final int CHILD_HEIGHT = 1;
private static final int DEFAULT_CHILD_SIZE = 100;

private final int[] childDimensions = new int[2];
private final RecyclerView view;

private int childSize = DEFAULT_CHILD_SIZE;
private boolean hasChildSize;
private int overScrollMode = ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS;
private final Rect tmpRect = new Rect();

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
public WrapToItemCountLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.view = null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
public WrapToItemCountLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    this.view = null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
public WrapToItemCountLinearLayoutManager(RecyclerView view) {
    super(view.getContext());
    this.view = view;
    this.overScrollMode = ViewCompat.getOverScrollMode(view);
}

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
public WrapToItemCountLinearLayoutManager(RecyclerView view, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(view.getContext(), orientation, reverseLayout);
    this.view = view;
    this.overScrollMode = ViewCompat.getOverScrollMode(view);
}

public void setOverScrollMode(int overScrollMode) {
    if (overScrollMode < ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS || overScrollMode > ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown overscroll mode: " + overScrollMode);
    if (this.view == null) throw new IllegalStateException("view == null");
    this.overScrollMode = overScrollMode;
    ViewCompat.setOverScrollMode(view, overScrollMode);
}

public static int makeUnspecifiedSpec() {
    return View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state, int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
    final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);

    final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
    final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);

    final boolean hasWidthSize = widthMode != View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED;
    final boolean hasHeightSize = heightMode != View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED;

    final boolean exactWidth = widthMode == View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
    final boolean exactHeight = heightMode == View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;

    final int unspecified = makeUnspecifiedSpec();

    if (exactWidth && exactHeight) {
        // in case of exact calculations for both dimensions let's use default "onMeasure" implementation
        super.onMeasure(recycler, state, widthSpec, heightSpec);
        return;
    }

    final boolean vertical = getOrientation() == VERTICAL;

    initChildDimensions(widthSize, heightSize, vertical);

    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    // it's possible to get scrap views in recycler which are bound to old (invalid) adapter entities. This
    // happens because their invalidation happens after "onMeasure" method. As a workaround let's clear the
    // recycler now (it should not cause any performance issues while scrolling as "onMeasure" is never
    // called whiles scrolling)
    recycler.clear();

    final int stateItemCount = state.getItemCount();
    final int adapterItemCount = numberOfChild;
    // adapter always contains actual data while state might contain old data (f.e. data before the animation is
    // done). As we want to measure the view with actual data we must use data from the adapter and not from  the
    // state
    for (int i = 0; i < adapterItemCount; i++) {
        if (vertical) {
            if (!hasChildSize) {
                if (i < stateItemCount) {
                    // we should not exceed state count, otherwise we'll get IndexOutOfBoundsException. For such items
                    // we will use previously calculated dimensions
                    measureChild(recycler, i, widthSize, unspecified, childDimensions);
                } else {
                    logMeasureWarning(i);
                }
            }
            height += childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT];
            if (i == 0) {
                width = childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH];
            }
            if (hasHeightSize && height >= heightSize) {
                break;
            }
        } else {
            if (!hasChildSize) {
                if (i < stateItemCount) {
                    // we should not exceed state count, otherwise we'll get IndexOutOfBoundsException. For such items
                    // we will use previously calculated dimensions
                    measureChild(recycler, i, unspecified, heightSize, childDimensions);
                } else {
                    logMeasureWarning(i);
                }
            }
            width += childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH];
            if (i == 0) {
                height = childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT];
            }
            if (hasWidthSize && width >= widthSize) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (exactWidth) {
        width = widthSize;
    } else {
        width += getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
        if (hasWidthSize) {
            width = Math.min(width, widthSize);
        }
    }

    if (exactHeight) {
        height = heightSize;
    } else {
        height += getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();
        if (hasHeightSize) {
            height = Math.min(height, heightSize);
        }
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

    if (view != null && overScrollMode == ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_IF_CONTENT_SCROLLS) {
        final boolean fit = (vertical && (!hasHeightSize || height < heightSize))
                || (!vertical && (!hasWidthSize || width < widthSize));

        ViewCompat.setOverScrollMode(view, fit ? ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER : ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);
    }
}

private void logMeasureWarning(int child) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.w("", "WrapToItemCountLinearLayoutManager Can't measure child #" + child + ", previously used dimensions will be reused." +
                "To remove this message either use #setChildSize() method or don't run RecyclerView animations");
    }
}

private void initChildDimensions(int width, int height, boolean vertical) {
    if (childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] != 0 || childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] != 0) {
        // already initialized, skipping
        return;
    }
    if (vertical) {
        childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] = width;
        childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] = childSize;
    } else {
        childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] = childSize;
        childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] = height;
    }
}

@Override
public void setOrientation(int orientation) {
    // might be called before the constructor of this class is called
    //noinspection ConstantConditions
    if (childDimensions != null) {
        if (getOrientation() != orientation) {
            childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] = 0;
            childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] = 0;
        }
    }
    super.setOrientation(orientation);
}

public void clearChildSize() {
    hasChildSize = false;
    setChildSize(DEFAULT_CHILD_SIZE);
}

public void setChildSize(int childSize) {
    hasChildSize = true;
    if (this.childSize != childSize) {
        this.childSize = childSize;
        requestLayout();
    }
}

private void measureChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSize, int heightSize, int[] dimensions) {
    final View child;
    try {
        child = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.w("", "WrapToItemCountLinearLayoutManager doesn't work well with animations. Consider switching them off", e);
        }
        return;
    }

    final RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

    final int hPadding = getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
    final int vPadding = getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();

    final int hMargin = p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
    final int vMargin = p.topMargin + p.bottomMargin;

    // we must make insets dirty in order calculateItemDecorationsForChild to work
    makeInsetsDirty(p);
    // this method should be called before any getXxxDecorationXxx() methods
    calculateItemDecorationsForChild(child, tmpRect);

    final int hDecoration = getRightDecorationWidth(child) + getLeftDecorationWidth(child);
    final int vDecoration = getTopDecorationHeight(child) + getBottomDecorationHeight(child);

    final int childWidthSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(widthSize, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST, hPadding + hMargin + hDecoration, p.width, canScrollHorizontally());

    final int childHeightSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(heightSize, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST, vPadding + vMargin + vDecoration, p.height, canScrollVertically());

    child.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);

    dimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] = getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(child) + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
    dimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] = getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(child) + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;

    // as view is recycled let's not keep old measured values
    makeInsetsDirty(p);
    recycler.recycleView(child);
}

private static void makeInsetsDirty(RecyclerView.LayoutParams p) {
    if (!canMakeInsetsDirty) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        if (insetsDirtyField == null) {
            insetsDirtyField = RecyclerView.LayoutParams.class.getDeclaredField("mInsetsDirty");
            insetsDirtyField.setAccessible(true);
        }
        insetsDirtyField.set(p, true);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        onMakeInsertDirtyFailed();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        onMakeInsertDirtyFailed();
    }
}

private static void onMakeInsertDirtyFailed() {
    canMakeInsetsDirty = false;
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.w("", "WrapToItemCountLinearLayoutManager Can't make LayoutParams insets dirty, decorations measurements might be incorrect");
    }
}
}
```

In this way I specified numberOfChild to wrap number of child in recyclerview. It was working perfectly until Support Library version 23.2.1 came with fixing recyclerview wrap content option. Now this LayoutManager is not behaving likewise(it's wrapping recyclerview height to all the child's height). I need a fix to solve this issue using latest Support Library version.

I've searched the S/O for solution but couldn't find one. Is there anyone who have found and solve the issue?